# Calculate checksum of a point number

Tags: c++, numbers, checksum

I'm trying to create a function which is able to calculate the checksum of any number, including floating point numbers.

For example:

```
360° = 3+6+0 = 9
180° = 1+8+0 = 9
90° = 9+0 = 9
45° = 4+5 = 9
22.5° = 2+2+5 = 9
11.25° = 1+1+2+5 = 9
5.625° = 5+6+2+5 = 18 = 1+8 = 9
2.8125° = 2+8+1+2+5 = 18 = 1+8 = 9
1.40625 = 1+4+0+6+2+5 = 18 = 1+8 = 9
0.703125 = 0+7+0+3+1+2+5 = 18 = 1+8 = 9
0.3515625 = 0+3+5+1+5+6+2+5 = 27 = 2+7 = 9
0.17578125 = 0+1+7+5+7+8+1+2+5 = 36 = 3+6 = 9
...
```

I wrote this little code, which calculates the checksum of an Integer:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int checksum(int param)
{
    int sum = 0;

    while (param > 0)
    {
        sum += param % 10;
        param /= 10;
    }

    while (sum > 9) { sum = checksum(sum); } 

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int number = 0;

    cout<<"Enter number:"<<endl;
    cin>> number;

    cout<< checksum(number);

    cin.get(); cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I improve it, so that it also works with floating point numbers?

**Background**

I try to find out if it is true that the pattern from my example will continue forever with the result of 9 as checksum.

**Update**

Unfortunattely C++ is not precise enough for this project. E.g. if i calculate `0.703125 / 2` then the result will be `0.3515625`, but in C++ the result is `0.351563`.
My Code: http://www.pasteall.org/61345/cpp

Comment: It looks like any negative param will yield a checksum of 0.  Is this intended?

Comment: Why don't you create the checksum from the bit representation?

Comment: You want 380, 180, 38, 18, 9 and 90 to all have the same checksum? Why?!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ? What makes you think so ?

Comment: You have a recursive call. There's no need for a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Let say you want to calculate checksum  upto 5 decimal point of  floating point number then simply multiply your floating point number with 100000 and take 'floor' then calculate checksum with your function.

**EDIT**

As float and double has precession problem it's better not to use them to calculate checksum for more digit(15 digit for double). For more digit use string representation of floating number.

Answer (score 1):

I never heard of a checksum on real numbers, by summing the digits. You should take the binary representation, 4 or 8 bytes, and sum those. That would make actual sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by myselve.

**Input:** `1.97654`

**Output:** `The checksum of 1.97654 is 5`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>       /* pow */
using namespace std;

int checksum(int param)
{
    int sum = 0;


    while (param > 0)
    {
        int r1 = param % 10;
        sum += r1;
        param /= 10;
    }

    while (sum > 9) { sum = checksum(sum); } 

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    string number; 
    cout<<"Enter number:"<<endl;
    cin>> number;

    double param_as_double      = stod(number);
    int front_part              = stoi(number);

    double after_point_part = param_as_double - front_part;

    ostringstream strs;
    strs << after_point_part;
    string after_point_part_str = strs.str();


    int nachkomma_len = after_point_part_str.length()-1;

    after_point_part *= pow(10.00,nachkomma_len-1);

    strs.str("");
    strs << after_point_part;
    after_point_part_str = strs.str();

    int after_point_part_int        = stoi(after_point_part_str);

    int SUM = 0;

    SUM = checksum(front_part);
    SUM += checksum(after_point_part_int);
    SUM = checksum(SUM);

    cout<<"The checksum of "<<number<<" is "<< SUM <<endl;

    cin.get(); cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Probably it is more code then necessary, but i am tired and therefor too lazy to improve it. I did not had enough time to test it for bugs yet, so im not sure if it is working for 100%.

Comment: Please tell me this is for a class and not a real world app.

Comment: This doesn't compute the checksum of a float, it computes the checksum of a string.

Comment: I edited the title, i was talking about point numbers. I am german and did not knew the right word for it.

Comment: @EdwardBlack They're not in the same format at all. One of them is a  number and the other is a representation. They're not even in the same category.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz They are in the same format. Look at `input: 1.97654`. This is a floating point number, so explain how this is not same format?

Comment: @EdwardBlack It's not a floating point number, it's a representation of a floating point number in base ten. Is 1/3 a floating point number? Do you agree that "1.97654", "1.9+0.7654" represent the same floating point number even though they are totally different strings? The number is the amount -- the thing that's the same regardless of how the amount is represented. "10", "0x0A", "9+1" and "ten" all represent the same number.

Comment: And understanding the difference between numbers and representations of numbers is extremely important to becoming a good programmer.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstand the word "floating point number". I was just talking about numbers with points e.g. `64.78`